Does the decomposability of $\mathbb{R}$ imply analytic LLPO?
By "BISH" I mean constructive mathematics without axiom of countable choice.
By $\mathbb{R}^f$ I mean real numbers as fundamental sequences of rational numbers and by $\mathbb{R}^d$ I mean real numbers as Dedekind cuts of rational numbers.
By "$dec(X)$" I mean the set $X$ is decomposable which means there exist two inhabited disjoint subsets of $X$, namely $A$ and $B$, such that $X=A \cup B$.
By "sequential $WLPO$" I mean the weak limited principle of omniscience which states that for all binary sequences, either all terms are 0 or this is not the case that all terms are 0.
By $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ I mean the weak limited principle of omniscience for $\mathbb{R}^d$, which states that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, either $x=0$ or $\neg(x=0)$.
By $LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ I mean the lesser limited principle of omniscience for $\mathbb{R}^d$, which states that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, either $x \le 0$ or $x \ge 0$.
I have shown that over BISH, $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ ($WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^f}$) implies $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ($\mathbb{R}^f$), which is trivial, and $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ($\mathbb{R}^f$) implies sequential $WLPO$.
After that, I proved over BISH, $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^f}$ and sequential $WLPO$ are equivalent. So I concluded that over BISH, $dec(\mathbb{R}^f)$ and $WLPO$ (analytic or sequential, they are the same here) are equivalent. But we know that over BISH, $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ is strictly stronger than sequential $WLPO$. So, my proof implies that $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is weaker than $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ and is stronger than sequential $WLPO$. So, there are three possiblities here:

$dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is strictly between $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ and sequential $WLPO$.
$dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is equivalent to $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$.
$dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is equivalent to sequential $WLPO$.

I know that 3 is not the case. Because I have a counter model.
Now, I observe something that may help us to prove that $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ implies $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$.
I could show that over BISH, $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$, implies $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$. The converse is also true and its proof is trivial. So, over BISH we have "$dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$+$LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ is equivalent to $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$". This result was independently interesting to me, because it says that what is the exact logical difference between $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ and $LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ (which we already knew that the latter is strictly weaker than the former). The logical difference is $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
Anyway, maybe $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is equivalent to $WLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$. In that case, instead of showing that directly, we can try to prove that $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ implies $LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ which seems easier.
I tried to show this; i.e I tried to show that $dec(\mathbb{R}^d)$ implies $LLPO_{\mathbb{R}^d}$, but I couldn't succeed. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.


Is $\mathbb{R}^f$ the same thing as Cauchy reals? That is, is it the set of fundamental sequences, or is it the set of fundamental sequences quotiented by an equivalence relation?

I mean the set of fundamental sequences quotiented by an equivalence relation.

It's not important in this question because you clearly stated what you mean, but in general it seems to me that it's a really bad idea to use the notation “BISH” to refer to constructive mathematics without axiom of countable choice, given that “BISH” is normally used (starting from Bridges & Richman, Varieties of Constructive Mathematics) to refer to Bishop's framework, which implies countable choice. So I would recommend finding some other notation, perhaps adding some kind of decoration around “BISH” to mean “without Choice”.

@Gro-Tsen I agree with your point. But I wonder, is there an agreed upon notation for "neutral constructive mathematics" (as the OP seems to intend), for example the mathematics that one can do inside every topos? Is, for example, something like $ \mathsf {BISH} ^ - $ used to denote Bishop-style mathematics without dependent or any other type of choice (which I suppose can be taken to be the above mentioned "neutral" constructive mathematics)?

@MohsenShahriari $\mathsf{IZF}$ (i.e., intuitionnistic ZF) is fairly close to “neutral constructive math“, so one might choose to use this. I generally start my constructive math questions with something like “this question is set in constructive mathematics without Choice, such as in the internal logic of a topos with natural numbers object, or in IZF”. But something like $\mathsf{BISH}^-$ might indeed be another possible notation. Maybe this is worthy of another question here.

(To lighten notations, let me simply write $\mathbb{R}$, instead of $\mathbb{R}^d$, for the set of Dedekind reals in what follows, since it is the only one that will appear.  For the sake of notational consistency, I will also slightly change the notation for the decomposability of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ instead of $\mathit{dec}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.)
I claim that, assuming what is written in the question is correct, $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$.
To see this, let me first remark that $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ can be restated as the existence of a function $\chi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ such that $\exists a\in\mathbb{R}.\chi(a)=0$ and $\exists b\in\mathbb{R}.\chi(b)=1$.  Replacing $\chi$ with $t \mapsto \chi(a+(b-a)t)$ we can assume $a=0$ and $b=1$, i.e., $\chi(0)=0$ and $\chi(1)=1$.  Further replacing $\chi$ with $t \mapsto \chi(\inf(1,|t|))$, we can demand $\chi(t)=1$ when $|t|\geq 1$.
Proposition. $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ together with (sequential) $\mathsf{WLPO}$ imply $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$.
Proof. As remarked above, from $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ we get a function $\chi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ such that $\chi(0)=0$ and $\chi(t)=1$ if $|t|\geq 1$.
Now let $c\in\mathbb{R}$.  Define a binary sequence $p_n$ by $p_n = \chi(2^n c)$.  If $c\mathrel{\#}0$, meaning $|c|>0$, then $\exists n.(p_n=1)$ (because there exists $n$ such that $2^{-n} \leq |c|$).  Contrapositively, if $\forall n.(p_n=0)$ then $c=0$; but the converse is obvious.  Thus, $(p_n)$ is the zero sequence iff $c=0$.  Now sequential $\mathsf{WLPO}$ tells us that either $(p_n)$ is the zero sequence or it is not, so we get $(c=0) \lor \neg (c=0)$, which is $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$. ∎
Now it is stated in the question (I did not try to prove this myself) that $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ implies (sequential) $\mathsf{WLPO}$.  So, together with the proposition above, this means that $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ implies $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$.  The converse, of course, is obvious (since $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$ asserts that $\mathbb{R}$ is decomposable as the disjoint union of $\{0\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : \neg(x=0)\}$).  So all of this proves that $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{WLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$, as claimed at the start.  (In particular, it implies $\mathsf{LLPO}_{\mathbb{R}}$, answering the titular question.)

This is a very nice answer. I think it is correct. Thank you very much.

@MohammadTahmasbi Now I'm curious to know how you proved that $\mathsf{DEC}(\mathbb{R})$ implies sequential $\mathsf{WLPO}$. If the proof is written down (or when it is in the future), please let me know! (E.g., by adding a comment here and/or by emailing me at the address given at the bottom of my web page.)

I sent you an email.

@MohammadTahmasbi Thank you. I wrote back to you (I am pointing this out because GMail tends to classify me as spam…). I very much hope to read the full text of whatever you're writing when it comes out!
